# PyCharm debugger errors whenever it hits a breakpoint

Tags: python, debugging, compiler-errors, pycharm, breakpoints

When debugging my program, whenever the debugger hits a breakpoint (I've confirmed this using `print` statements), it sends the following error to the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd_frame.py", line 408, in trace_dispatch
    self.doWaitSuspend(thread, frame, event, arg)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd_frame.py", line 53, in doWaitSuspend
    self._args[0].doWaitSuspend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1445, in doWaitSuspend
    activate_function()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/matplotlibtools.py", line 136, in activate_pylab
pylab.show._needmain = False
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'show'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2357, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1777, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/pkillam/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 332, in <module>
    profile.run(main())
  File "/Users/pkillam/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 225, in main
    xyw_intensity_array, xywi_point_array, x_catalog, y_catalog, w_catalog = readFile(input_filename[6])
  File "/Users/pkillam/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 83, in readFile
    if (areaScan):
  File "/Users/pkillam/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 83, in readFile
    if (areaScan):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd_frame.py", line 408, in trace_dispatch
    self.doWaitSuspend(thread, frame, event, arg)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd_frame.py", line 53, in doWaitSuspend
    self._args[0].doWaitSuspend(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1445, in doWaitSuspend
    activate_function()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/matplotlibtools.py", line 136, in activate_pylab
pylab.show._needmain = False
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'show'
```

This happens at the line, wherever I put the breakpoint throughout my code.  It will always error at that line.  Any ideas as to its cause, and/or a solution?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've been looking at JetBrains community forum and could't find a solution. I'll report to them, hopefully they will give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of obvious but I'd look to make sure your breakpoint is syntactically correct. If you know the error occurs only where you place a break point then it must be how you are writing it out.

Comment: I'm adding the breakpoints through pycharm, as in, you click next to the line of code and a red circle appears, and when the debugger hits that line, it pauses the program so you can see all the variables.  That kind of breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above I had the same issue, After consulting with Jet Brains community forums I could find a solution. Our matplotlibtools library installation is corrupted.

Install it again or upgrade it and the error should go away.

Comment: I tried in every possible way to upgrade/install matplotlibtools to fix it, same results.